# Is there no support for pipeline calls with reactive redis in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I have a micro-service which is written in Springboot. I wanted to explore how reactive approach can improve the performance of my system.
The flow of part I planned on picking for this reactive approach is ->
Getting message stream from kafka -> batching them and making a call to redis

I have implemented reactive kafka but unable to implement pipelining in redis using reactive approach. Single calls seem to work fine. But is there no support for a reactive Flux/Mono on pipelined/batch calls? What is the right way to do it?

Below is the code for my non reactive approach ->

```
    public List<List<Object>> executeBatchedCommands(@NotNull List<CommandArgs<String, String>> commandArgsList , BatchedCommandType commandType) {
    List<List<Object>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    RedisAsyncCommands<String, String> asyncCommands = client.connect().async();
    asyncCommands.setAutoFlushCommands(false);
    List<RedisFuture<List<Object>>> futureResults = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CommandArgs<String, String> commandArgs : commandArgsList) {
        RedisFuture<List<Object>> future = asyncCommands.dispatch(
                commandType,
                new ArrayOutput<>(StringCodec.UTF8),
                commandArgs);
        futureResults.add(future);
    }
    asyncCommands.flushCommands();
    for (RedisFuture<List<Object>> future : futureResults) {
        try {
            results.add(future.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    asyncCommands.setAutoFlushCommands(true);
    return results;
}
```

This is what i want (a redis reactive stream listener which will accept queries i want it to execute which will be coming from kafka )

```
public class CustomReactiveRedisTemplate extends ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> {

public CustomReactiveRedisTemplate(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                   RedisSerializationContext<String, String> serializationContext) {
    super(connectionFactory, serializationContext);
}

public Mono<Void> customCommand(CommandKeyword commandType, List<CommandArgs<String, String>> commandArgsList) {
    return execute(connection -> {
        connection.setCommands().....
    }).then();
}
```

}

or a ReactiveStreamOperation

```
 ReactiveStreamOperations<String, String, T> streamOperations = redisTemplate.opsForStream();
```

But cant figure out how to run a custom query.

Comment: And what have you tried for the reactive approach?

Comment: @M.Deinum added in the question

Comment: You provided a customized (why) redistemplate? Not what you tried? You should be retrieving a flux of commands from kafka and pass that to your template. You shouldn't be collecting them into a list.

Comment: @M.Deinum Will that not be too many roundtrips to redis? I am creating a list of the commands so that there are less calls made to redis. Also the command is GEOADD which i dont understand how to implement in this case.
For reference every 10 seconds i get around 5k commands

Comment: Why would that be too many roundtrips? You have a streaming approach, but suddenly block in the middle? Send the command, flush periodically and continue. What you currently do is stream, block to list, list to stream, try to shoehorn the stream in how we did blocking with list before. I have to state that I'm very novice in Redis, you have to make sure you also use the reactive GeoAdd command and not the previous one. You might need to use the reactive client (instead of the blocking one and instead of the template for this).

Comment: Sure I understand what you mean, but the issue is I also have to make call to tile38 database which uses redis/io.lettuce , the commands supported by tile38 are not present in reactive redis client. Earlier i was using  List<CommandArgs<String, String>> to execute the necessary, i was sending queries like "SET fleet data POINT 28.3 32.4" and everything was working fine. With kafka i am getting these coordinates all i need to do it put them in tile38 which connects just like redis does with the port change. Thats why i am creating this List of commands. With stream there is no direct function.

Comment: Why not, you can do the same but using a `Flux`. The reactive lettuce parts have the same methods as the async one (at least the flush, dispatch etc).